# Why does Eclipse doesn't display a number less than zero?

Tags: java, math, double

Every time  I run this test program it display, `0.0 instead of 0.5`

Does anyone know how to fix this in Eclipse?

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[]args){

        double  distance;

        distance = 1/2;

        System.out.println(distance);
    }

}
```

Comment: You are using int literals. Just make one of these operands as double type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your division is Integer division. There is no fault of Eclipse. Try following:

```
distance = 1/2.0;
```

**OR**

```
distance = 1.0/2;
```

> Output:0.5